# Color(int, int, int) vs Color(float, float, float) ambiguous call

Tags: c++, call, ambiguous

How can I resolve the ambiguous call between these two in C++?

```
Color(int, int, int)
Color(float, float, float)
```

It is both ambiguous when the values are hardcoded i.e. `Color(1, 2, 3)` and when they are variables `Color(r, g, b)`. Why wouldn't the compiler resolve according to data type? In variable form?

EDIT:
Sorry, too much C++ makes me forget there's a other languages.
And there is not much "full code" that was all about it.

```
float x, y, z;
int r, g, b;
Color(1, 2, 3); // ambiguous
Color(1.0, 2.0, 3.0); // ambiguous
Color(r, g, b); // ambiguous  <--- this one is a real pain
Color((int)r, (int)g, (int)b); // ambiguous
Color(x, y, z); //OK
Color(1u, 2u, 3u); //OK
Color(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f); //OK
```

Comment: There will be no ambiguity with `Color(1, 2, 3)`, but with `Color(1., 2., 3.)`. Please show full code. Otherwise noone can help you.

Comment: Please start by resolving the language.

Comment: Please include details like which language you are using, which library, and the full text of the error message.

Comment: Tell us which language you're using (and which compiler would help), show us the exact calls you're trying to make, and what the error messages are.

Comment: sorry all... too engrossed in C++ forgot there's other languages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you have declared

```
Color(unsigned, unsigned, unsigned);
Color(float, float, float);
```

ie, all three args must be either `float` or `unsigned`.  If you try to call it with other types (such as `int` or `double`), its ambiguous -- the compiler doesn't know which you want as both are just a good (or as bad if you prefer).  You could improve things a bit by declaring more overloads:

```
Color(int, int, int);
Color(double, double, double);
```

but you'd still get ambiguity errors if try to call it with mixed types.

Comment: wow that's right. that's how i become dumb when intellisense is not working. sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

The type of a floating-point literal is `double`, not `float`. In general, you should be using `double` unless you have a specific reason for using `float`, such as needing to consume less memory. As other answers have mentioned, you seem to have declared:

```
Color(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int);
Color(float, float, float);
```

Which means that invoking, e.g., `Color(int, int, int)` has two possible conversions, neither of which is preferred. You can fix this by declaring:

```
Color(int, int, int);
Color(double, double, double);
```

Instead, and performing any conversions you need within the class itself, or invoking the constructor as:

```
Color((unsigned int)r, (unsigned int)g, (unsigned int)b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language, but you can probably cast them, if you are using C# or C++.

e.g. for C#:
`Color((int)r, (int)g, (int)b)`
or
`Color((float)r, (float)g, (float)b)`

Answer (score 0):

Given your test cases, particularly `Color(r,g,b)`, I'd bet you don't have `Color(int, int, int)`, but `Color(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)`.  That's why you're getting ambiguous calls that you're not expecting.