# Clang ambiguous call (int, float, double)

Tags: c++, macos, clang, ambiguous

I have to compile an API on Mac using Clang that uses a construct similar to this:

```
#define TRUE 1

void func(int a) {
    // ...
}

void func(double a) {
    // ...
}

void func(float a) {
    // ...
}

func(TRUE);
```

Clang complains that the call to `func()` is ambiguous while MSVC and GCC don't. Is there an option for Clang that it will choose the integer variant in this case?

Edit: This is the original output of the compilation

```
../../resource/_api/c4d_basedocument.cpp:263:52: error: conversion from 'int' to 'const GeData' is ambiguous
        this->SetParameter(DescLevel(DOCUMENT_USERCHANGE),TRUE,DESCFLAGS_SET_DONTCHECKMINMAX);
                                                          ^~~~
../../resource/_api/ge_sys_math.h:21:15: note: expanded from macro 'TRUE'
        #define TRUE    1
                        ^
../../resource/_api/c4d_gedata.h:97:3: note: candidate constructor
                GeData(double n)
                ^
../../resource/_api/c4d_gedata.h:110:3: note: candidate constructor
                GeData(LONG n)
                ^
../../resource/_api/c4d_gedata.h:116:3: note: candidate constructor
                GeData(SReal n)
                ^
```

`LONG` is an integral type, `SReal` a floating point type.

Comment: Are you sure, that this full test? I have a lot of compilers on my machine, and clang 3.2, and clang 3.3 doesn't produce any warrnings or errors during compilation of your test.

Comment: A related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909406/colorint-int-int-vs-colorfloat-float-float-ambiguous-call?rq=1 mentions issues due to the integer that gets passed being in fact an unsigned.  Is the #define you show above actually that simple?

Comment: `TRUE` is a macro that expands to `1`; `1` has type `int`. There is no ambiguity. I strongly doubt that this is the actual code that produced the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I might misunderstand some technical details and maybe the boiled down example does not map 1-to-1 to the original case. I have added the compiler output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had time to investigate more time in looking into the original build project and see that I was missing a compiler option. Interesting thing is, that it only results in additional definitions set which seems to solve the "ambiguousity".

```
-include _api/ge_mac_flags.h
```

Which looks like

```
#ifndef __GE_MAC_FLAGS__
#define __GE_MAC_FLAGS__

#define __MAC
#define __DEBUGGING__                                                                               // avoid conflicts with DebugAssert() definition for the Mac

#if __LP64__
    #define __C4D_64BIT
#endif

#endif
```

Solves it!